# Abstraction, an OOPs vs non-OOPs concept

Tags: java, oop

I am reading OOPS concepts and got stuck on Abstraction. I am not able to fully understand the concept. As I am feeling that it doesn't belongs to OOPS only. It was also used in C. But how 
java abstraction different from C language abstraction. I know it is not a good question
for this forum but i am not able to get the perfect answer.

Comment: you are correct, that it is a general programming concept and certainly not restricted to OOPs.

Comment: Not sure about what the question is. You don't understand abstraction? btw, C does not have abstraction, C++ does. The main difference between java and C++ is that in java you can only inherit one class, while in C++ you may inherit several. To (somewhat) solve this, in java you have interfaces.

Comment: @caerolus: C programs can certainly be written in a way to use abstraction. It may not be as direct to do this in a structural language, but it certainly can be done.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sure it can be done, but since C is not object-oriented, I think it's best to stick to actual object-oriented languages and concepts rather than workarounds. My feeling anyway

Comment: But abstraction means is hiding the inner details. If i am calling a library function or a custom function then it is also abstraction. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: I'm with @caerolus - what exactly is the question?

Comment: My questions is that while reading C I haven't saw any text describing for Abstraction but while reading Java or any other OOPS language it suddenly comes in the frame. I feel abstraction is used in all the programming languages created so far.

Comment: @caerolus - you can do abstraction in C using static methods and file static variables. I think Stroustrup said that every C program written in K & R was object oriented.

Comment: My bad. I read 'abstraction' and thought of polymorphism and abstarct classes. Still, I wonder if that doesn't have to do with the question

Comment: @DurgaDutt What you are referring to is encapsulation, not abstraction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

abstraction means to hide or to separate the complex details of one part of code to other part. say, you have to use a method that does complex calculation, and gives some result. So instead of writing your method inline, its better to write it in a method that just expose the signature (params and return type). in that way your caller (of method) remains unaware of complex code behind the method.

in general, when you use library function in c/c++ or APIs in java, it is also an abstraction.

So indeed, abstraction is not only OOP, but a general concept can be applied anywhere (even beyond the programming).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me one more thing that Is oops is more abstract than the previous structured languages as it introduced encapsulation and access specifiers?

Comment: @DurgaDutt: nothing is "more abstract". It's easier to implement abstraction in OOPs due to these constructs, that's all.

Comment: After all, every compiler/programming language is nothing more than an iteration of a basic Turing Machine with added syntactic sugar.

Comment: "to hide or to separate the complex details of one part of code to other part" is encapsulation, not abstraction.

Comment: my dear @Param , encapsulation is bundling data and methods together. though it in turn hides the detail to provide abstraction. so better, double check yourself before pointing fingers.